# Can I make antlr 4 combine generated classes?

Tags: antlr4

I do a simple MIB file parser.

Antlr 4 tool generates following files:

```
MibParser.java
MibLexer.java

MibListener.java
MibBaseListener.java
```

Can I force antlr 4 to combine pairs of those files to reduce clutter?
Any  command line switch ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `-no-listener` and `-no-visitor` options to suppress the generation of two of those files if you don't need them. In addition to not having an option to combine files currently, I completely disagree that the creation of 4 files represents "clutter" in this context, so I would argue strongly against the implementation of such an option.

Comment: Sometimes so much flexibility is not required (doesn't hurt though):)

Answer (score 1):

> *Łukasz Bownik wrote:*
>
> *Can I force antlr 4 to combine pairs of those files to reduce clutter?*

No.